# error with urdf file at launch

Tags: urdf, ros-melodic, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to run this urdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="wam-v" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://freddy/mesh/WAM-V.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="base_link_collision">
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://freddy/mesh/WAM-V.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="247.07"/>
      <inertia ixx="200" ixy="0.03" ixz="3.09" iyy="500" iyz="-0.05" izz="165.39"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <link name="base_footprint"/>
  <joint name="base_link_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 1.84"/>
    <parent link="base_footprint"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>


  <link name="front_camera_link"/>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>


  <joint name="front_camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="1.2 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="front_camera_link"/>
  </joint>



  <link name="left_camera_link"/>
  <joint name="left_camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 1.57079632679" xyz="0 0.5 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_camera_link"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="right_camera_link"/>
  <joint name="right_camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 -1.57079632679" xyz="0 -0.5 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_camera_link"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="rear_camera_link"/>
  <joint name="rear_camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 3.14159265359" xyz="-0.5 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="rear_camera_link"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="scan"/>
  <joint name="scan_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="1.5 0 -1"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="scan"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="right_motor">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://freddy/mesh/PROPELLER.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="right_motor_collision">
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://freddy/mesh/PROPELLER.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.01"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00086" ixy="0.00" ixz="0.00" iyy="0.00086" iyz="0.00" izz="0.0017"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="right_motor_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="-1.5 -1.027 -1.705"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_motor"/>
    <limit effort="0.5293" velocity="1003.14159265359"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="left_motor">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://freddy/mesh/PROPELLER.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="left_motor_collision">
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://freddy/mesh/PROPELLER.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.01"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00086" ixy="0.00" ixz="0.00" iyy="0.00086" iyz="0.00" izz="0.0017"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="left_motor_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="-1.5 1.027 -1.705"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_motor"/>
    <limit effort="0.5293" velocity="1003.14159265359"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="gps"/>
  <joint name="gps_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.8 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="gps"/>
  </joint>
  <transmission name="right_motor_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="right_motor_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="right_motor_actuator">
      <hardwareInterface>VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>30</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="left_motor_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="left_motor_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="left_motor_actuator">
      <hardwareInterface>VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>30</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so" name="gazebo_ros_control">
      <robotNamespace>wam_v</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libsimple_buoyancy_plugin.so" name="simple_buoyancy_base_right">
      <target_link>base_footprint</target_link>
      <cob_x>0.5</cob_x>
      <cob_y>-1.05</cob_y>
      <cob_z>0.5</cob_z>
      <bbox_x>4.0</bbox_x>
      <bbox_y>0.5</bbox_y>
      <bbox_z>0.5</bbox_z>
      <publish_data>true</publish_data>
      <bbox_prefix>right_bbox</bbox_prefix>
      <force_offset_x>0.03</force_offset_x>
      <force_offset_y>-1.05</force_offset_y>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libsimple_buoyancy_plugin.so" name="simple_buoyancy_base_left">
      <target_link>base_footprint</target_link>
      <cob_x>0.5</cob_x>
      <cob_y>1.05</cob_y>
      <cob_z>0.5</cob_z>
      <bbox_x>4.0</bbox_x>
      <bbox_y>0.5</bbox_y>
      <bbox_z>0.5</bbox_z>
      <publish_data>true</publish_data>
      <bbox_prefix>left_bbox</bbox_prefix>
      <force_offset_x>0.03</force_offset_x>
      <force_offset_y>1.05</force_offset_y>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libsimple_buoyancy_plugin.so" name="simple_buoyancy_motor_right">
      <target_link>right_motor</target_link>
      <position_reference_link>base_footprint</position_reference_link>
      <cob_x>-1.5</cob_x>
      <cob_y>-1</cob_y>
      <cob_z>0.2</cob_z>
      <bbox_x>0.1</bbox_x>
      <bbox_y>0.2</bbox_y>
      <bbox_z>0.2</bbox_z>
      <publish_data>true</publish_data>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libsimple_buoyancy_plugin.so" name="simple_buoyancy_motor_left">
      <target_link>left_motor</target_link>
      <position_reference_link>base_footprint</position_reference_link>
      <cob_x>-1.5</cob_x>
      <cob_y>1</cob_y>
      <cob_z>0.2</cob_z>
      <bbox_x>0.1</bbox_x>
      <bbox_y>0.2</bbox_y>
      <bbox_z>0.2</bbox_z>
      <publish_data>true</publish_data>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so" name="novatel_gps_sim">
      <alwaysOn>1</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>10</updateRate>
      <bodyName>gps</bodyName>
      <topicName>fix</topicName>
      <velocityTopicName>fix_velocity</velocityTopicName>
      <frameId>gps</frameId>
      <drift>5.0 5.0 5.0</drift>
      <gaussianNoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</gaussianNoise>
      <velocityDrift>0 0 0</velocityDrift>
      <velocityGaussianNoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</velocityGaussianNoise>
      <referenceLatitude>135.52491</referenceLatitude>
      <referenceLongitude>34.822634</referenceLongitude>
      <referenceHeading>0</referenceHeading>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libsimple_driving_force_plugin.so" name="simple_driving_force_left">
      <target_link>left_motor</target_link>
      <target_joint>left_motor_joint</target_joint>
      <driving_force_controller>/wam_v/right_driving_force_controller</driving_force_controller>
      <joint_state_topic>/wam_v/joint_states</joint_state_topic>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libsimple_driving_force_plugin.so" name="simple_driving_force_right">
      <target_link>right_motor</target_link>
      <target_joint>right_motor_joint</target_joint>
      <driving_force_controller>/wam_v/left_driving_force_controller</driving_force_controller>
      <joint_state_topic>/wam_v/joint_states</joint_state_topic>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu.so" name="imu_plugin">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
      <topicName>imu</topicName>
      <serviceName>imu_service</serviceName>
      <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
      <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libwater_surface_friction_plugin.so" name="imu_plugin">
      <target_link>base_footprint</target_link>
      <mu_linear>20</mu_linear>
      <mu_angular>20</mu_angular>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="front_camera_link">
    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
      <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so" name="camera_controller">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>/wam_v/camera/front</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>front_camera_link</frameName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="right_camera_link">
    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
      <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so" name="camera_controller">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>/wam_v/camera/right</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>right_camera_link</frameName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="left_camera_link">
    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
      <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so" name="camera_controller">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>/wam_v/camera/left</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>left_camera_link</frameName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="rear_camera_link">
    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
      <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so" name="camera_controller">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>/wam_v/camera/rear</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>rear_camera_link</frameName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <joint name="velodyne_base_mount_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.8 0 0.3"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="velodyne_base_link"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="velodyne_base_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.1" iyz="0" izz="0.1"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://velodyne_description/meshes/VLP16_base_1.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://velodyne_description/meshes/VLP16_base_2.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.03585"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.0717" radius="0.0516"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="velodyne_base_scan_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.0377"/>
    <parent link="velodyne_base_link"/>
    <child link="velodyne"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="velodyne">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.1" iyz="0" izz="0.1"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 -0.0377"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://velodyne_description/meshes/VLP16_scan.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <!-- Gazebo requires the velodyne_gazebo_plugins package -->
  <gazebo reference="velodyne">
    <sensor name="velodyne-VLP16" type="ray">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>1875</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-3.14159265359</min_angle>
            <max_angle> 3.14159265359</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>16</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.261799387799</min_angle>
            <max_angle> 0.261799387799</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.055</min>
          <max>140.0</max>
          <resolution>0.001</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.0</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_velodyne_laser.so" name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller">
        <topicName>/velodyne_points</topicName>
        <frameName>/velodyne</frameName>
        <min_range>0.9</min_range>
        <max_range>130.0</max_range>
        <gaussianNoise>0.008</gaussianNoise>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="scan">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
    <sensor name="scan_sensor" type="ray">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <update_rate>40</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>720</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
            <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>1</min>
          <max>30.0</max>
          <resolution>0.001</resolution>
        </range>
      </ray>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so" name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller">
        <topicName>/scan</topicName>
        <frameName>scan</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

The error has something to do with the `front_camera_link`:

```
XML parsing error: mismatched tag: line 47, column 4
when processing file: /home/philip/cbs_ws/src/freddy/urdf/wam-v.urdf

Check that:
 - Your XML is well-formed
 - You have the xacro xmlns declaration: xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"
RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/opt/ros/melodic/share/xacro/xacro.py', '/home/philip/cbs_ws/src/freddy/urdf/wam-v.urdf']] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

All tags seem to match to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410906/error-with-urdf-file-at-launch/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> <link name="front_camera_link"/>

You are closing the link tag. The `/` character should not be there.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-12-28**:
@Mike Scheutzow Thanks, it works now, I don't want to have to redo this entire question again in another thread so if it's allowed, I'm also trying to get the 'libgazebo_ros_camera.so` plugin for the front camera to work. I've checked my computer and know I have this plugin. it' simply not publishing.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-12-29**:
I have never used that camera plugin, but I would try an experiment: delete all the other cameras to see if a single camera works. The fact that you use the identical `name=` for all cameras is questionable to me.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-12-29**:
@Mike Scheutzow it works now, my format was wring I guess. Would you happen to know how to use the `buoyancy plugin` correctly?